# How to create a single RDD from multiple rows in HBase table?

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

What would be the most efficient way to get multiple rows from a HBase table to a RDD?

For the moment I read all my table and I filter my RDD with a list of row key that I want to keep.

```
val conf = HBaseConf.hbaseConf
conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, table)

val hBaseRDD = ss.sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(
  conf,
  classOf[TableInputFormat],
  classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable],
  classOf[Result])

hBaseRDD.map { case (writable, res) =>
  ...
}.filter(...)
```